# How to create flip panes in swift/ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, flip

I am creating an app for my kid:

[image]

The image has 5 section, each in a different color. Each section has a black box on each side of the section.

What I want to do is when touching a black box in a section I want that section to vertical flip around and in the process of flipping I want the whole screen to follow flipping vertical to a new screen.

Ex) I press the left black box in green section. The green sections starts to vertical flip around (to the left or counter-clockwise) its axis in the middle of the section. And when it has flipped/turned some 10 degrees I want the rest of the sections to follow and when all sections has flipped a new all green page is shown.

I hope I made it clear what I want. Is this possible? How can it be done in Swift?

I have seen the vertical page flipper but I want a bit more stylish:). I have seen other samples with flipping an image, but not this two-part flipping.

Thanks to all clever people,
Micael

Comment: I don't get it. Please post an image—it's worth more than your 221 words. Use imgur or whatever if you can't post on SO.

Comment: I edited the text. Click "here" to see image.

Comment: yes, that is possible to do it, you can use the `QuartzCore.framework` doing such _2.5D_ transitions with setting the perspective properly.

Comment: Please supply some sample code. I havn't worked with QuartzCore framework.